# What is the name for this concept?

Tags: programming-languages, powershell, coding-style

**I have a negligible attention span, and since I'm immersed in *La Vida Powershell* at the moment, my code will be formatted as such**

I apologize in advance if this has been discussed elsewhere, but since my problem is that I don't know what this is called, my googling efforts have been understandibly fruitless.

imagine three functions:

```
function GrowGrapes(){...} #grows grapes.
function MakeWine(){...} #uses said grapes to make wine
function DrinkWine(){...} #drinks said wine
```

if the first fails, then you don't want to, and must not, attempt the 2nd.  If the 2nd fails, or is never ran, then there is no point in ever attempting to perform the 3rd.

rather than a big obnoxious nest of IF statements like this...

```
IF ([bool]GrowGrapes()) {
   IF ([bool]MakeWine()) {
      DrinkWine()
   }
}
```

in certain languages (I *BELIEVE* I learned this in reference to C...) you can do the following:

```
IF ([bool]GrowGrapes() -AND [bool]MakeWine()) {DrinkWine()}
```

or even

```
$rslt = ([bool]GrowGrapes() -AND [bool]MakeWine()) -AND [bool]DrinkWine()
```

and trust that the 2nd half of your conditional would only ever execute if the first came back as true/success/whatever.

likewise you could OR two expressions, and trust that the 2nd would only ever be executed and tested if the first came back as false

```
[bool]MakeWine() -OR [bool]BuyWine()      #only attempt to purchase wine if 
                                          #the attempt to make it has failed
```

My question is: What is this behavior called?  Also, does powershell support it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called short-circuit evaluation, and Powershell does support it. See the sections on `-and` and `-or` [here](http://www.pavleck.net/powershell-cookbook/apa.html#windows_powershell_logical_operators).

**EDIT** The original link appears to be broken (as of 2014-11-05); a suitable alternative is [about_Logical_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx).

Comment: Mind the feature (or bug?): in contrast to other programming languages `-AND` and `-OR` in PowerShell have the same precedence:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/285170/and-should-have-higher-priority-than-or-as-it-is-in-other-programming-languages

Comment: That's it!  Was absolutely killing me trying to remember that.  Thanks!

Comment: The equivalent for Bash (and probably other Unix shells) is the `&&` operator: `foo && bar` executes `foo`, and then it will only execute `bar` if `foo` succeeds (exit status 0).  Likewise `foo || bar` only executes `bar` if `foo` fails (exit status non-0).

Answer (score 2):

This quite a common idiom in Perl, from where it migrated into Ruby:

```
do_something or die
```

where `die` is some error handling routine and

```
do_something and do_something_else
```

where `do_something_else` is meaningless if `do_something` fails.

As was mentioned in the other answers, this (ab)uses short-circuiting behavior and/or lazy evaluation of boolean operators, which not all languages have.

Note that this obviously assumes that `do_something` returns a boolean value that indicates success or failure, which also means that its *real* work is some side-effect.

A more structured way of doing something similar would be to use an `Error` Monad. See [*Yet Another Monad Tutorial (part 5: error-handling monads)*](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/5103.html) for an approachable introduction to the `Error` Monad, and the whole article series for an introduction to the concept of Monads in general.

Comment: So is it implied that short-circuiting is 'bad' from a coding style point of view?  When writing/reading code for/from others, is it preferred to keep the explicit if/then setup for readability?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell supports exceptions, so first I would suggest that you make functions throw exceptions when they fail.  Then the short circuiting would happen for you.

If you can't do that for some reason, then this is another version of short circuiting logic.

```
GrowGrapes
if ($?) { ## If last command successful
    MakeWine
}
if ($?) { ## If last command successful
    DrinkWine
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Not sure if Powershell supports it...